# valgrind complains doing a very simple strtok in c

Tags: c++, c, valgrind, tokenize, strtok

Hi I'm trying to tokenize a string by loading an entire file into a `char[]` using `fread`.
For some strange reason it is not always working, and valgrind complains in this very small sample program.

Given an input like `test.txt`

```
first
second
```

And the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


//returns the filesize in bytes
size_t fsize(const char* fname){
  struct stat st ;
  stat(fname,&st);
  return st.st_size;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  if(NULL==(fp=fopen(argv[1],"r"))){
    fprintf(stderr,"\t-> Error reading file:%s\n",argv[1]);
    return 0;
  }
  char buffer[fsize(argv[1])];
  fread(buffer,sizeof(char),fsize(argv[1]),fp);
  char *str = strtok(buffer," \t\n");

  while(NULL!=str){
    fprintf(stderr,"token is:%s with strlen:%lu\n",str,strlen(str));
    str = strtok(NULL," \t\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

compiling like

```
gcc test.c -std=c99 -ggdb
```

running like

```
./a.out test.txt
```

thanks

Comment: strtok is obsolete and has several issues. don't use it.

Comment: What would you recommend instead? For simple stuff, that doesn't have to be threadsafe etc. I still find it veryusefull

Comment: Well, obviously it's not so simple, otherwise `valgrind` would not complain.

Comment: So valgrind would never complain on obviously simple matters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `buffer` size should be `filesize + 1`. The `+1` is for the `null` char.

```
filesize = fsize(argv[1]);
char buffer[filesize + 1];
```

Also `fread` does not put a `\0` at the end of the string. So you'll have to do it yourself as:

```
fread(buffer,sizeof(char),filesize,fp);
buffer[filesize] = 0;
```

Comment: Can variable (filesize + 1), not a constant, be used as array size...?

Answer (score 5):

From this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c/53921#53921):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::string str = "The quick brown fox";

  // construct a stream from the string
  std::istringstream stream(str);

  // use stream iterators to copy the stream to the vector
  // as whitespace separated strings
  std::istream_iterator<std::string> it(stream), end;

  std::vector<std::string> results(it, end);

  // results = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox"]
}
```

SO much easier than dealing with those nasty C-strings that keep banging you on the head.

And you know what's great about using higher-order methods ? It takes less screen estate and is easier to understand.

Comment: +1, The question is tagged both C and C++, but many times that means that *I am programming C++, but can use a C solution* even if in this case the code and filename seem to indicate plain C. Anyway this is worth the upvote (people doing C++ will surely read this) even if it may not suit the user.

Answer (score 2):

`buffer` is not null-terminated.  You need to make it one byte larger than the size of the file, and you need to set the last byte to be `\0`.

Answer (score 2):

Your buffer must be `filesize + 1` and you will also need to set the terminating 0:

```
int size = fsize(argv[1]);
char buffer[size + 1];
buffer[size] ='\0';
```

Also, you should probably allocate the buffer on the heap instead of the stack...

Answer (score 1):

Your buffer is too small.  Try this:

```
int fileSize = fsize(argv[1]);
char buffer[fileSize + 1]; 
buffer[fileSize] = 0;
```

right before your call to `fread`.